# Handling file relocation with jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a directory containing images, am marshalling the images filename (complete path of image) to a xml file present in the same directory. If the user moves the directory to some other place then the path in the xml file is invalid. I use the image path in the xml file path while marshalling, but if the directory is moved then am facing issues. What can I do to overcome this problem?

I tried overriding the unmarshal method but am unable to get the base directory of xml file. Is there any way to get the xml file path whose file we want to unmarshall while unmarshalling?

Any other suggestion to resolve this problem are welcome.

Comment: The XML file and the images are located in the _same_ directory? If so, then don't use absolute paths, but simply use the file name in the XML file.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I have to use absolute paths as the images are loaded from the path present in the xml file, if I use just the filename then I won't be able to load the images into my application. Is there any way to fetch the xml file path in the unmarshal method?

Comment: Well ... You have to load the XML file first, don't you? That means that you already know the directory.